# Can I convert shares in an index ETF into shares of the index constituents?

Tags: etf, index-fund, market-indexes, djia

Suppose I own many shares of the SPDR Dow Jones Industrial Average ETF Trust (NYSE Arca: DIA). How can I convert those shares in DIA into shares of the 30 components of the DJIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** it can be done, but not by small market participants.

The reason that ETFs that follow a market indexes so closely is because an arbitrage mechanism exists that allows *conversion* between ETF shares and shares of the underlying basket of securities.  The prospectus of the ETF provides the details, but it goes along something like this:

A holder of 100,000 shares of the ETF can ask the ETF to convert them to the corresponding number of shares of the index that the ETF represents, and vice versa - a holder of the relevant number of shares of the index can exchange them for 100,000 shares of the ETF.  This quantity is called a 'creation unit'.

If this mechanism is effective, then market participants can buy or sell ETF shares and convert them to index component and sell or buy them at a profit.

Comment: If I actually possess 100,000 shares of DIA (worth approximately $24 million at the moment), will I be able to convert those ETF shares into shares of the companies in the index?

Comment: If you are a market maker or broker dealer, then perhaps. *"Redemption of Units -
Only certain institutional investors (typically market makers or other broker-dealers) are permitted to purchase or redeem Units directly with the Trust, and they may do so only in large blocks of 50,000 Units known as “Creation Units.”* - from the DIA prospectus

Answer (score 1):

You can not. You can BUY the shares, but there is no conversion order or service or something.